# Chaining multiple required rewrites in .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have at present 2 rewrites that are supposed to occur on any given url,

The first redirects any url matching the pattern `%DOMAIN%/mcc-*` to `show.php?id=mcc-*`
The second redirects any url without the .php extension to the page as if it had one.

The first rewrite gets called and works, but the second does not.

I have tried swapping the places of the rewrites, but the result is the same, the 'Add Extension' rewrite is never called, even on pages that don't redirect to show.php

```
ErrorDocument 404 /error/404.php

Options All -Indexes -MultiViews

RewriteEngine On

# Silent Redirect from any url ending with mcc-* to show.php?id=mcc-*
# This works as intended.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(mcc-[\d]+)/?$ show.php?id=$1 [QSA,NC]

# Allow urls to not include the .php extension
# This is not not being called.
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}/$1.php -f [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ $1.php [L]
```

Is there someway to get both of these conditionals to run, or at the very least run the second if the first doesn't match?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With your shown samples please try following .htaccess rules file. Please make sure to clear your browser cache before testing your URLs.

```
ErrorDocument 404 /error/404.php
Options All -Indexes -MultiViews

RewriteEngine ON

# Allow urls to not include the .php extension
# This is not not being called.
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.php -f [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ $1.php [L]

# Silent Redirect from any url ending with mcc-* to show.php?id=mcc-*
# This works as intended.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(mcc-[\d]+)/?$ show.php?id=$1 [QSA,NC]
```

Comment: I realize now, that after adding the `RewriteBase /` before the 'Add Extension' rewrite that I hadn't attempted again to swap the order, thank you again for helping my figure out my .htaccess

Comment: I notice that the code you posted already made that small change, I admit my knowledge on apache config is limited, and the documentation is at the very least difficult to follow if not lacking. IE I don't actually know the difference between them

Comment: @RWolfe, Sure, please make sure to clear your browser cache before testing your URLs.